# Equivalance Operator - Perfect Secrecy

Tags: encryption, xor, perfect-secrecy, random-oracle-model, forward-secrecy

The equivalance operator is the inverse of the XOR operator, it's symmetric. Would this mean that it would also provide theoretical perfect secrecy just like XOR?

#### XOR

`x ⊕ y = (x ∨ y ) ∧ ¬ (x ∧ y )`

#### EQUIVALENCE

`x ≡ y = ¬ (x ⊕ y)`

[image]

There is no information leakage in theory if you just take the inverse of a perfectly symmetric function, it has to be perfect in both ways in theory.

What are you thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, for any [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) operator $\odot$, we see that $x \odot y$ gives perfect security, assuming that $y$ is uniformly random over all possible group members.

The $\equiv$ operation is a group operation, with the group members being $\{0, 1\}$, with $1$ being the identity.  Hence, yes, it gives perfect security.